# how server can identify ajax request?

Tags: ajax, web-scraping

i am trying to send request from my localhost to ebay servers , i am using postman to do so. 
the request is the same request which this ebay page send `http://www.fees.ebay.com/feeweb/feecalculator`
when you press on the `calculate fees` button .

the request should return json response, but i am unable to do that in my postman , please find my request bellow:
how ebay can identify that my response is not ajax request ?

```
POST /feeweb/calculate HTTP/1.1
Host: www.fees.ebay.com
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://www.fees.ebay.com/feeweb/feecalculator
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

locale=en_US_MAIN&catlevel1=2984&dp_cat-level1=Baby&catlevel2=20394&dp_cat-level2=athing+%26+Grooming&catlevel3=113814&dp_cat-level3=Bath+Tubs&saleformat=saleformat&site_id=0&RlogId=t6e%2560cpfg%253C%253Dsm%257Eaf%2560qba%252840%253A702-15753cbd4ec-0xfe&dp_store=Basic&rb-discount=0&freeshipping=1&value_pack_info=Value+Pack+is+Gallery+Plus%2C+Listing+Designer%2C+and+Subtitle+packaged+together+for+a+discount.&store=1&n_reserveprice=0&n_finalsaleprice=100&finalsaleprice=%24100.00
```

EDIT :
here is the response headers :

```
Content-Encoding → gzip
Content-Length → 2312
Content-Type → text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date → Sat, 22 Oct 2016 15:10:25 GMT
ETag → 6faadcbec2626c16a5eb2715c89aa47f
Last-Modified → Sat, 22 Oct 2016 14:31:15 GMT
Server → Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

response body:

```
From collectibles to cars, buy and sell all kinds of items on eBay



Page Not Responding 



            The eBay page or feature you are attempting to access is not responding.
Please try the options below:
Try to access the feature directly from the eBay Home Page, instead of using a bookmark.
Wait a few minutes and try to access the feature again.
If you have waited ten to fifteen minutes and you still can't access your page:
Check our Announcement Board to see if the feature is currently unavailable.
If what you are looking for is unavailable, you may still be able to access other parts of the site from the eBay Home page
```

Comment: I don't think eBay rejects your post request because it is Ajax or not, but rather that the requests is coming from a foreign server (your localhost), thus blocking the request completely.

Comment: @AuditeMarlow i am using postman, it sent the same request as it send from chrome with the same ip address

Comment: You don't show the response; seeing the response and response-headers would help. There are several problems with your POST above, e.g. double Content-Type headers.

Comment: @Cyberfox thank you very much the problem was the double Content-Type , i really appreciate that. i've been long time trying to solve it with no luck. thanks i wish you all the best in every thing you do.